# EOFExcpetion while deserialization by byte array

Tags: java, serialization, compression

I've got a EOFException while decompress and deserialization a byte array.
Stacktrace:

> java.io.EOFException
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2324)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2793)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:799)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
>       at com.chuck.pack.ResourcePacket.load(ResourcePacket.java:44)

```
// Functions related to load

public static ResourcePacket load(String packetName) {
    try {
        byte[] bytes = uncompress(fileToByteArray(new File(packetName)));
        ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        ObjectInputStream objIn = new ObjectInputStream(in); // Error occured here
        return (ResourcePacket) objIn.readObject();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

private static byte[] uncompress(byte[] bytes) {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Inflater ifl = new Inflater();
        ifl.setInput(bytes);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4*1024];
        while(ifl.finished()) {
            int size = ifl.inflate(buffer);
            out.write(buffer, 0, size);
        }
        out.close();
        return out.toByteArray();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error while load");
    }
    return null;
}

private static byte[] fileToByteArray(File file) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        fileInputStream.read(bytes);
        fileInputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return bytes;
}

// Functions related to save

public void save() {
    try {
        byte[] bytes = compress(toByteArray());
        //byte[] bytes = toByteArray();
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(packetName);
        fileOutputStream.write(bytes);
        fileOutputStream.close();
        System.out.println("Packet saved (" + resourceFiles.length + " Files)");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}

private byte[] compress(byte[] bytes) {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Deflater dfl = new Deflater();
        dfl.setLevel(Deflater.BEST_SPEED);
        dfl.setInput(bytes);
        dfl.finish();
        byte[] tmp = new byte[4*1024];
        while(!dfl.finished())  {
            int size = dfl.deflate(tmp);
            out.write(tmp, 0, size);
        }
        out.close();
        return out.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error while save");
    }
    System.exit(-1);
    return null;
}

private byte[] toByteArray() {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        out.writeObject(this);
        byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
        return bytes;
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error while create byte array");
    }
    System.exit(-1);
    return null;
}
```

Someone an idee to fix this?

Comment: When the program learns you're Chuck Norris, it will fix itself. Merry Christmas :)

Comment: That would be nice ;) Also, Merry Christmas

Comment: We need to see how the object was serialized in the first place, and also, how it was compressed. It could be a problem with the serialization, or it could be a problem with an error that causes a mismatch between the data that was compressed and the result after decompression.

Comment: I call load to load and save to save. The other you can see in source code.

Comment: Yeah i'm an idiot, what a missing '!' can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `uncompress(..)` method the while loop:

```
while(ifl.finished()) {
    int size = ifl.inflate(buffer);
    out.write(buffer, 0, size);
}
```

should be

```
while(!ifl.finished()) {
    int size = ifl.inflate(buffer);
    out.write(buffer, 0, size);
}
```

Otherwise the result of `uncompress(..)` is an empty byte array if the method terminates.

Comment: Yes, thanks after a long time search i found itself.